# php -r not working for installing the PHPixie framework

Tags: php, phpixie

First I'll just say that I'm totally new to PHP and I'm just trying to follow this tutorial [PHPixie download instructions](http://phpixie.com/tutorials/download-instructions/)

Also I should mention that I'm trying to install this on my webhost.

Instructions from tutorial:

```
cd /home/fairy/projects/
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('http://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
```

This is the error:

```
Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r
```

Comment: Did you check Alternative in your manual

Comment: If you are new to PHP then you should not be using a framework yet IMO.

Comment: @fruityp Well, I only want to create a simple poll and there is tutorial specifically for doing that on the PHPixie framework website.

Comment: I assume by the dir structure your using unix/linux? What OS are you running?

Comment: @vijay4vijju Please explain what manual are talking about?

Comment: @fruityp My webhost is linux. I'm using windows at the moment.

Comment: I might add it's shared hosting.

Comment: @Chakotay That's going to be the problem. They probably have removed the `-r` option for security reasons. If you need to try out a VPS;  Amazon Web Services EC2 micro instances are free for a year. http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: @fruityp Thanks for sharing that. looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Why not download the packaged official snapshot from the website instead? http://phpixie.com/phpixie.zip

Comment: Also if your looking for some mac install instructions, check here: http://www.stellarbuild.com/blog/article/install-phpixie-on-a-mac